# How to toggle between the most recent active tabs in Firefox via Keyboard shortcut?

Tags: windows-10, firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, firefox-extensions, browser-tabs

How to toggle between (two) most recent tabs in Firefox via keyboard shortcut without using any mice for this simple task?

*Situation: in Firefox 50 I have say twenty seven tabs open conserning my research thesis, all organised neatly in chronological order (by date etc) I will number them for clarity purposes:*
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 25, 26, 27

I must compare the technical specs of many tabs with eachother. Two tabs at once. At this moment say tab nr 12 and tab nr 24. So, I want to switch back and forth between the current tab (24) and the next best previously ACTIVE tab (12).

**Q1. What keyboard shortcut lets me jump from the current active tab (24), to the tab that was just a moment ago activated by me (12)?**

**Q2. And of course: what keyboard shortcut lets me jump forward again from tab (12) to the latest activated tab (24)?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### How can I toggle between (two) most recent tabs in Firefox?

Install the [Tab Toggle](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-toggle/) Firefox Add-on:

> This add-on is helpful when you want to switch between two tabs. By pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>q</kbd> it'll switch between current tab and previous tab. Customizing hotkey will come in future versions.

Confirmed as working on Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit, Firefox 50.1.0

Comment: Awesome that dit the trick mate! Thought this will be a bounty question but you helped me out before giving the chance to wrap the bounty present for ya :) :) Thanks Sir! +1 and accepted. Confirmed working in Win10 Professional English 64bit.

Comment: Not a problem. You don't really have enough rep to give out bounties yet ...

Comment: Lol you are right sir, i never understood why reputation is strictkly bound to one sub site only. I have plenty of rep and no less than 19 GOLD medals on the stackoverflow. Over here im poor :) but still thankful. At least there is an extension! How you knew about this extension? Link to a/your site with more usefull extensions/tips ??

Comment: @Sam Nothing more than my google-fu - I searched for "firefox toggle tabs" - the extension is the 3rd result :) And I don't have a website at the moment :/

Comment: @ David  well with your incredible trackrecord, reputation and search skills and wills I bet you ganna make a nice unique website... if you do then let us know the link! (PS what topics interest you endlessly? some words comma separated will do)

Answer (score 1):

Q1. CTRL-9

Q2. Don't think you can

Comment: Q1. That only works if you are jumping back to tab 9. It wont work for tab 24 - to tab 12. Q2. See my answer for a working solution.

Comment: See this list of shortcuts: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly#w_windows-tabs

Comment: Ah OK. I still have a fully working solution though :)

Comment: anwers for q1: Doesnt work on my Firefox 50. answer for q2. i dont like being told "Sorry, Cannot be done" but nevertheless +1 for raising the challenge of something that apparently can be done once we know how.